# Best practice for waiting for javascript .find() results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

I often have to pass ternary operators to values that depend on the result of a `.find()` method because it returns `undefined` before it finds the value:

```
const getValue = stateDataA => {
    let value = stateDataA.find(item => item.name === stateDataB[0]).name;
    return value;
}
```

This is usually returns "cannot find property 'name' of undefined". Below is how I get around this, but I know this can't be optimal:

```
let value = stateDataA.find(item => item.name === stateDataB[0]) ? stateDataA.find(item => item.name === stateDataB[0]).name : "placeholder";
```

My data is often passed through props using `connect()` and I have the primary component wrapped in a container that only loads once state is loaded, so I think the problem is just the amount of time it takes to `find()` my value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "*I think the problem is just the amount of time it takes to `find()` my value.*" - no, it's not. `find` is synchronous, there are no race conditions here. It's just that `stateDataA` doesn't contain an item with the desired `.name` if it returns `undefined`. Probably something about the "*container that only loads once state is loaded*" is broken, or the state is just not what you expect it to be.

Comment: You're right, explaining that it's synchronous clarifies that. Not sure why, when logging to the console, it first returns undefined before immediately returning the value. The container has conditions in the useEffect hook to only load the child component if the props are loaded. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

[`?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) are new but very welcome members in the family of javascript operators:

```js
let a = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]

console.log(a.find(x => x.name === 2)?.name ?? 'placeholder')
console.log(a.find(x => x.name === 5)?.name ?? 'placeholder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `item?.name`. This will check whether `item` is undefined. If no, then it'll skip the following operations.